# (found: [object Promise]) with Material UI and DexieJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui, dexie

This is my first time working with DexieJS and Material UI so I might be missing a key part. But here are the relevant parts of my code:

**Subscreen.tsx**

```
const [fightersArray, setFightersArray] = useState<FighterEntity[]>([]);

useEffect(()=>{
    loadFighters();
},[]);

const loadFighters = async ()=>{
    const fighters = await databaseManager.getFightersWithNoOrgs();
    setFightersArray(fighters);   
}

...

return (
   <DataGrid
      rows={fightersArray}
      columns={columns}
      checkboxSelection
      onSelectionModelChange={(newSelection) =>{
       setSelectedFighters(newSelection.selectionModel);
      }}
   />
)
```

**DatabaseManager.tsx**

```
public async getFightersWithNoOrgs() : Promise<FighterEntity[]>{
        const fighters = await this.db.fighters.filter((fighter)=> {
            return fighter.currentOrgID == null
        }).toArray();
        return fighters;
    }
```

And this is the error message I'm getting on when I first navigate to the page

```
Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

I am able to console.log out the array i'm returning from the databaseManager, so I know there are results and they look normal, like an array of objects.

I use to have this bit of code work when I wasn't using a promise structure or DexieJS. So I've introduced it with this change, but I think I have my promise structure correct and my understanding of React hooks.

I am also getting a few other errors, but I think they are just cascading off this original one. Happy to provide them if they might be relevant.

Comment: I think my issue relates to the toArray() since it returns a promise. But i'm unsure what it expects me to do. I figured the async/await would wait for that to resolve before sending back a response.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the issue, and it didn't lie in the code I posted above.

In setting up the columns I have the following bit of code:

```
    {   
        field: 'ranking', 
        headerName: 'Rank', 
        width: 100,
        renderCell : (params : GridCellParams)=>(
            <span>{getRanking(params)}</span>
        )
    },
```

getRanking is actually an async function and it's throwing the issue here.

Silly mistake on my end, but hopefully this helps someone else!